# How to create new maven projects efficiently and quickly

Tags: java, maven

I have a habit/policy of creating many smaller maven projects rather than bigger monolithic ones. By doing this I have ended up with several projects, and several things to do. For example, I maintain each of these projects in their own GitHub repository, which becomes an additional task. Then the worse part of this is, pushing to the maven central. It seems pretty complex, and I have multiple accounts to deal with. It becomes more difficult, as the POM becomes more and more complex with features like GraalVM, JavaFX, JSweet, Maven shade plugin etc.

I was wondering how others are dealing with this problem.

I take two examples

- JavaFX / GluonVM, for example, has a web tool -  https://start.gluon.io which allows us to select what all we need and creates a maven project for us with those settings. This is over and above having archetypes.
- Similarly, Quarkus website also has something, and they also have a CLI tool to create new projects https://quarkus.io/guides/cli-tooling#project-creation

I think maven archetypes are not going to work because requirements evolve over time. For example, when I start I might not be interested in GraalVM or publishing the code to Maven central (or even if I am interested I might not be ready yet).

Other avenues are Gradle, SBT, Mill, and all other kinds of build tools.
However, I find the support is best for maven, as in, all plugins are most up to date in maven only - for example, the JavaFX GraalVM plugin for maven seems to be more stable than their Gradle plugin. I am more used to Maven.

I even considered building a DSL for maven, in Java and running it with JBang. Someone already walked on that route and ended up being one of the developers of the mill build toolkit.

What are other known effective, efficient, worth exploring ways of making maven projects, fast and efficiently?  I say efficiently because I can't memorize so many settings and configurations, there must be an easier way around this, which I can teach to the new people joining the team also.

Comment: First of all you need to ask yourself if it is sensible to build so many JARs and push them to Maven Central. Probably you are better of with fewer projects, e.g. using multi module. Secondly, you can centralize configuration in parent POMs.

Comment: @JFabianMeier I use multi-module but eve those I felt better to shift to individual projects because if one module is giving trouble or something, it affects the compilation and build process of others also in multi-module.  But I will seriously look in and see if I am creating this complication for myself, or it is genuine. Thanks for the feedback.